# Subset a dataframe based on a list of values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, rows

I have a dataframe with participants' IDs and observations. I also have a list of the IDs of some participants that need to be removed from this data frame - I want to remove the whole row associated with this participant ID. I have tried the following:

```
ListtoRemove <- as.list(ListtoRemove)
NewDataFrame <-    
subset(OldDataFrame,OldDataFrame$ParticipantsIDs!=ListtoRemove)
```

This gives two warnings and does not remove the rows.

```
1: In `!=.default`(DemographicsALL$subject_label, AllSibs) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
```

Example of the data:

```
structure(list(ParticipantsIDs = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 5L), .Label = c("B0002", "B001", "B003", "B004", "L004", 
"M003"), class = "factor"), Age = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 6L), .Label = c("15", "23", "45", "53", "65", "98"), class =      
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ListtoRemove <- as.list(B004,M003)
```

Comment: Is the `dput` from `NewDataFrame`

Comment: What are `B004` and `M003`? Variables (as written) or strings (currently a syntax error)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data (ListtoRemove slightly edited - I hope this is correct):

```
data=structure(c("B001", "B0002", "B003", "B004", "M003", "L004", 
"45", "15", "53", "23", "65", "98"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("ParticipantsIDs", "Age")))
ListtoRemove <- list("B004","M003")
```

What about:

```
data_subset=data[!data[,"ParticipantsIDs"] %in% unlist(ListtoRemove),]
```

Output:

```
> data_subset
     ParticipantsIDs Age 
[1,] "B001"          "45"
[2,] "B0002"         "15"
[3,] "B003"          "53"
[4,] "L004"          "98"
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
NewDataFrame[ !NewDataFrame[,1] %in% unlist(ListtoRemove), ]
#      ParticipantsIDs Age 
# [1,] "B001"          "45"
# [2,] "B0002"         "15"
# [3,] "B003"          "53"
# [4,] "L004"          "98"
```

I think there might be some mistakes in the code you provided.

1. You use `subset` in a way that suggests `NewDataFrame` is a `data.frame`, but you gave us a `matrix`. My code works either way, but your `subset` is going to fail (in a different way than you showed).
2. `as.list(B004, M003)` is perhaps wrong on up to three points:

   - if those are names of variables, then we do not have them;
   - if those are strings, then we see

     ```r
     as.list(B004, M003)
     # Error in as.list(B004, M003) : object 'B004' not found
     ```
   - `as.list(1, 2, 3)` only `list`-ifies the first argument, here 2 and 3 are ignored (so we would have only seen `"B004"`, not `M003`; perhaps you meant `list("B004", "M003")` or `c("B004", "M003")`?

Instead, I used

```r
ListtoRemove <- list("B004","M003")
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, sorry, I forgot to make it a data frame when I was making the example. There was no way for me to use the original data frame.

Comment: *"no way ... data frame"* ... next time, please consider `dput(head(x))` instead of giving us an incorrect structure. When you search for questions with the [tag:r] tag ([url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)), read the top paragraph, it suggests to *"Use `dput()` for data"*.

Comment: thank you will do, in any case this thread did give me the answer I needed.

Comment: @MonikaGrigorova [Maybe consider accepting it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a data frame, an easier-to-read way to do it would be:

```
# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(ParticipantsIDs = c("B001", "B0002", "B003", "B004", "M003", "L004"), 
                        Age = c("45", "15", "53", "23", "65", "98"))

# vector containing ids to remove
ids.remove <- c('B004','M003')

df

# subset df by rows where ParticipantsIDs are not found in ids.remove
subset(df, !(ParticipantsIDs %in% ids.remove))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
data_subset = data[!data[, "ParticipantsIDs"] %in% unlist(ListtoRemove), ]
```

and it worked well.